# Skipped Deploy: Project: OpenGLDemo.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ 2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am using
Windows 10 Family x64
Visual studio Community 2015 14.0.25.123.00 update 2
Xamarin 4.0.3.214
Xamarin.Android 6.0.3.5

I am trying to compile and execute with the virtual device Xamarin_Android_API_15
the solution found there :
https://github.com/burf2000/OpenGLXamarin.git

First I had the following error:
"major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler. [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded."
So I uninstalled JDK 6

Now I have the following error:
Skipped Deploy: Project: OpenGLDemo.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU
Project not selected to build for this solution configuration

In my Solution Configuration Properties, Build is checked for OpenGLDemo.Droid for any CPU
I tried to delete all folders in obj/ and bin/
I tried to Clean the Project
I tried to Unload and Reload the Project.

I still have the same error... HELP

Answer (score 12):

Go to `Build->Configuration Manager` and check `Deploy` checkbox for your project.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it, I don't really know how:
I changed from Active(Debug) to Debug then I unchecked Build for OpenGLDemo.UITests
then from Any CPU to x86, I got a message like "processor mismatch"
then back to Any CPU and I could deploy...